# apiRTC.disconnect(); does not appear to work with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc

I have setup both a classic ASP site and a cordova angularjs ionic app that allow video conferencing with apiRTC.  When the user logs out of the web site apiRTC.disconnect(); works so a new apiRTC.init can be used when a different user logs in.

In the app, apiRTC.disconnect(); does not do anything so the user appears to still be online to other users, and when a different user logs in, it has no affect since init does not work.

Can you look at apiRTC.disconnect() under cordova and see if there is a general issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the issue by doing a test using our tutorial : https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-mobile and adding a button that call apiRTC.disconnect() on Android.
Others users receive the disconnection information and remove the user from the connectedUsersList.

Comment: i don't get it because I am doing the same thing, just inside the logout function.

Comment: The usage of apiRTC.disconnect() is not mandatory. If your application is stop, the server will detect that your user has left and send an updatePresence "offline" to other users

Comment: Do not want to exit the application, I want to just log the user out, and apiRTC.disconnect() is not working,  at least for me.  Also when the next user logs in, the first users session is still live, so they cannot start their session.

Comment: You have to check why the apiRTC.disconnect() doesn't work in your application : do you have any error in your logs ?

Comment: I just recompiled and tested (no change to my code) and it now works.  So something has been fixed in https://cloud.apizee.com/apiRTC/apiRTC-latest.min.js which is how I load your scripts.

Comment: OK this is a good news as this is now working in your application.For your information, last modification of apiRTC-latest.min.js was done the 8th of August.